# Multiplying issue in algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm still new to algorithms. But, I think I'm getting the hand of it. However, in my code, I'm having trouble with the last part of my program. Specifically, I'm trying to write a function that multiplies the numbers and outputs the result. `

```
    var prod=0;
    prod=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    prod=prod*a[i];
    }
document.write("Product= "+prod+"<br>");
```

`

I've looked everywhere to solve my question.

Full code:

```
var i,n;
var max=0;
var min=0;
var sum=0;
var avg=0;
var prod=0;

n=parseInt(prompt("Enter array size"));
var a=new Array(n);

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
a[i]=parseInt(prompt("Enter numbers"));
}
// determine which number is the greatest
max=a[0];
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{
if(max<a[i])
max=a[i];
}

// determine which number is the least
min=a[0];
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{
if(min>a[i])
min=a[i];
}

// determine the sum of all the numbers
sum=0;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
sum=sum+a[i];
}

// determine the mean of the numbers
avg=sum/n;

document.write("Array Elements : – ");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
document.write(a[i]*" ");
}

// determine the product of all the numbers
prod=0;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
prod=prod*a[i];
}

document.write("<br>"+"Maximum= "+max+"<br>");
document.write("Minimum Number= "+min+"<br>");
document.write("Sum of Array Numbers= "+sum+"<br>");
document.write("Average= "+avg+"<br>");
document.write("Product= "+prod+"<br>");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your function?

Comment: What is the issue, actually ?

Comment: Oh, my bad. I'm still new to this. It's the product part: the issue was: // determine the product of all the numbers
prod=0;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
prod=prod*a[i];
}..but someone helped me out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

So, you're saying `prod=prod*a[i];` when the initial value of prod is 0. Change it to 1 and you're good to go.

Comment: Hey, thanks Ademola. That didn't occurred to me - replacing "0" with "1".